# Modify Array PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to add the value of the next item in the array to the previous key.

```
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "{"_1711375007552_552"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "title"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "Test 1"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "link"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "#test"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "enabled"
  [6]=>
  string(21) "1"},"_1711375014003_3"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "title"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "Test 2"
  [9]=>
  string(4) "link"
  [10]=>
  string(4) "#123"
  [11]=>
  string(7) "enabled"
  [12]=>
  string(4) "1"}}"
}
```

So I would actually like to have the same array but with the same keys as the values, something like this:

```
array{
  array[0]{
     ["title"]=>
     string(5) "Test 1"
     ["link"]=>
     string(4) "#test"
     ["enabled"]=>
     string(7) "1"
  }
  array[1]{
     ["title"]=>
     string(5) "Test 2"
     ["link"]=>
     string(4) "#link"
     ["enabled"]=>
     string(7) "1"
  }  
}
```

Comment: It looks as though you are already processing some data, which could be JSON.  Can you post the original data you have?

Comment: I receive the data in string format:

string(147) "{"_1711375007552_552":{"title":"Test 1","link":"#test","enabled":"1"},"_1711375014003_3":{"title":"Test 2","link":"#123","enabled":"1"}}"

Comment: Try using `print_r(json_decode($stringName));` to see if it decodes as JSON.